# How did all of my upvotes for one answer disappeared?

Tags: discussion, answers, upvotes

I am not sure what happened, so I will explain the best I know.

So long time ago I found an old question with outdated answers and decided to write a [better up to date explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22446770/1090562). People liked it and over a period of many months I collected significant amount of upvotes (do not remember the number, but I believe 25+. The number is actually irrelevant).

Few minutes ago I saw +10 score, followed it and saw that someone upvoted my answer. But strangely enough right now I see that all my upvotes are gone.

I do not believe that the upvotes were lost because of cheater/deleted user, because 1) I have not lost reputation in a couple of months, 2) I highly doubt that 25+ upvotes were from fake users.

So how did this happened?

---

Thanks to everyone for taking a look. Dominant idea is that I forgot what actually happened. This is highly possible, also as every mad man I stand my ground telling that I remember writing long answer about html minification which was well received.

I will take some time looking through reputation change to find the times when the answer I claim I wrote was upvoted before. If I will find, I will update the answer. If not, will look for the excersises to improve my memory. One more time thanks to everyone

---

**P.S.** After minutes of searching through reputation tab, I finally able to say that no, I am not mad, no I still remember things and do not live in parallel universe. So [I really had the answer which is almost the same as the one I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22447444/1090562) and it got 33 upvotes. The question was really similar and was deleted. That was the source of my confusion.

Comment: That answer never received upvotes other than that one vote. Are you sure you didn't confuse that answer with another one, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612028/export-mongodb-aggregation-framework-result-to-a-new-collection/19600746#19600746) perhaps? [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476945/how-do-i-run-redis-on-windows/19579610#19579610) too is a late answer with around the same score.

Comment: According to the question timeline -- http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1306792/timeline -- your answer has only ever received one vote, today. Either you're mistaken or this is a bug.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: seeing as there are 2 'late' answers the OP posted, both around the 25 vote mark and all 3 of similar age, I'd say the OP is confused. I see no evidence whatsoever that there is anything strange going on here.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me, @MartijnPieters.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I found the answer which made me confused. Updated my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you misremember how well that answer did.

The Internet Archive holds 2 copies of that question dated between now and the time you posted your answer:

- Copy from [July 2014](http://web.archive.org/web/20140723114614/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306792/why-minify-assets-and-not-the-markup), your answer has a score of 0.
- Copy from [May 2015](http://web.archive.org/web/20150508223938/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306792/why-minify-assets-and-not-the-markup). Still a score of 0.

The answer never received a vote until today.

Perhaps you got confused between that post and either one of these two 'late' answers you posted in late 2013:

- [Export mongodb aggregation framework result to a new collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612028/export-mongodb-aggregation-framework-result-to-a-new-collection/19600746#19600746) – Question from November 2012, your answer dated October 2013, score 26
- [How do I run Redis on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476945/how-do-i-run-redis-on-windows/19579610#19579610) – Question from June 2011, your answer dated October 2013, score 24

Comment: Thank you. Now I am totally confused. Because I clearly remember that I had a long answer about html minification and it was well received. Will be looking through the reputation change to see whether I really lost my mind.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Are you sure you don't have a dupe account belonging to a split personality? ;)

Comment: Questioning your own sanity is actually a symptom of good mental health.

Comment: @SalvadorDali could have possibly had a dream about it that was real life like, and so s/he just remembers it as being real life, so not a memory remembrance issue, but just categorization issue.

Comment: @CRABOLO I found the reason for my confusion. I updated the question with explanation. One more time, thank you Martijn for investigation.

Comment: @SalvadorDali: Ah, one more reason to *close posts as duplicates* then. Fewer things to keep track of! And my apologies, I should have looked further than a very narrow 24-26 votes band when looking at your answers.